# Why is `request.method` returning a string (instead of a symbol)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I thought `request.method` is supposed to return a symbol like `:get`, `:put` etc. ?
But instead in the controller action, I am getting `GET` as a String!

Am I doing something wrong?

In `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
  member do
    get 'some_action'
  end
end
```

In a view .erb:

```
<%= link_to "Some Action",some_action_post_path %>
```

In `PostsController`:

```
def some_action
  p request.method               # => "GET"
  p request.method.class.name    # => "String"
  if request.method == :get
    #does not get called
  end
end
```

Ps. I'm using Rails 3.0.3 on Ruby 1.8.7 p330

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Works as designed - it is supposed to return a string :)
So, use the string. Different topic: you can convert between strings and syms with to_s and to_sym, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone coming at this question while converting from Rails 2.x, it's worth noting that the request.method call used to return symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but we also have these now:

- `request.method_symbol` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-method_symbol)
- `request.request_method_symbol` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-request_method_symbol)

If you just want to know if it is a certain verb, you can use query methods like this:

- `request.get?`
- `request.post?`

etc